# Off-the-shelf UI component for table-to-table field mapping?

Tags: java, c#, metadata

I wanted to check with the community if there is any existing off-the-shelf component or library that handles table-to-table field mappings, specifically, defining meta-data for the data fields.

[Example (from Salesforce's UI):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5gUb.png)

Simply put, my inputs would be a list of source fields and target fields, and the UI component should allow the user to map one to the other, or have a source field not map to any target field at all.

Since I've seen this UI component so many times in various corporate systems, now that I need it I wanted to see if it was out there in one form or another before we start building. I'd be particularly interested in C# or Web (JS) oriented solutions, but would take anything for reference.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Comment: I think you might get good answers from a more discussion-oriented site (like a forum or even reddit), considering the nature of your question. StackOverflow's QA model contradicts with these kinds of "suggest a library" questions because there's no "best answer". More about that in StackFlowed's link and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: There may not be a best answer but most answers are subject to the developer's own style and opinion anyways.  People have their preferences and it would be great for them to share their knowledgeable insight into this isssue and find a coherent solution which would inspire newcomers of the industry.